# How to move files to and from folders using shutil and os in python?

Tags: python, directory, shutil, python-os

So, I'm looking to move some images from my downloads folder to my pictures folder  (Windows 11), but I am continually being met with errors. Here is my code:

```
import shutil 
import os 
source = r"C:\Users\zaner\Downloads\AI.jpg\"
path = r"C:\Users\zaner\Downloads\AI.jpg\"
print("Before Copy: ")
print(os.listdir(path))
perm = os.stat(source).st_mode
print("File Permission mode:", perm, "\n")


destination = r"C:\Users\zaner\OneDrive\Pictures\Camera Roll\"

dest = shutil.copy(source, destination)
```

I have tried using every kind of slash, including back, front, and none at all. I even used double at one point. I am met with either not a real directory errors or an unterminated string literal. I am stumped tbh, so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error? Can you share the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to mention files to which need to be relocated

```
import shutil
import os 
source = r"C:\Users\zaner\Downloads\AI.jpg\"
path = r"C:\Users\zaner\Downloads\AI.jpg\"
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    new_source = source + file
    new_path = path + file
    shutil.copy(new_source, new_path)
```

or you can simply do

```
import os
source = r"C:\Users\zaner\Downloads\AI.jpg\"
path = r"C:\Users\zaner\Downloads\AI.jpg\"

os.system(f"cp source{*} path")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am recieving an error that says unterminated string literal when I try to use the code as it is. I think it is that the slash at the end extends past the quotation. Every other slash variation results in an invalid directory name though. I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: if you are talking about second solution, i missed the `)` symbol there and edited it now.

Comment: hey, so I am still getting this error: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\zaner\\Downloads\\AI.jpg'. TBH I have no clue what to do at this point.

Comment: this look like a file name , if it a  directory then add `\\` after `AI.jpg`

Comment: Hey, I finally have a working program. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

in case if you are looking for multiple .jpg file

```
source = r"C:\Users\zaner\Downloads\"
destination = r"C:\Users\zaner\OneDrive\Pictures\Camera Roll\"
for file in os.listdir(source):
    if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        shutil.copy(source + file, destination)
```

Comment: Hey, I finally have something that works, thanks for your help